# docker compose how to mount entrypoint and then use it

Tags: docker-compose

I have a service in the docker compose as follows.

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.18.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/localhost/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      - webapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network
```

I get the error

```
Cannot start service nginx: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown            
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

How can i do this

Answer (score 7):

I have to use `["/bin/sh","/entrypoint.sh"]`

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.18.0-alpine
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/localhost/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","/entrypoint.sh"]
    depends_on:
      - webapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough information about your entrypoint script, config file and the web app minimal information.

Sometimes when you create a file on your host machine it lacks some permissions to be executed by some users in your docker container, so Iwould think about checking the permissions for that file by running:

```sh
ls -l
```

that will give you all permissions about that file, and maybe that's why it's telling you permission is denied try adding execution permission running `chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh`.

> I usually do that using a dockerfile when working on a script from my context.

**dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine

COPY /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]:
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./    
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/localhost/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - webapp
    networks:
      - nginx_network
```

Then try to run:

```sh
docker-compose up --build
```

> make sure both files are in the same directory.